# Remove grid lines in dotplot without modifying underlying trellis parameters

Tags: r, lattice

I want to remove the light gray grid lines from a Lattice dotplot.  After searching R help pages, Sarkar's book, and the web, the one answer I've found is [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-August/170797.html) post, which explains that you can set the grid line width to zero for all dotplots using this magic:

```
## turn off grid lines
d1 <- trellis.par.get("dot.line")
d1$lwd <- 0  ## hack -- set line width to 0
trellis.par.set("dot.line",d1)
```

Example:  Try `dotplot(VADeaths[,"Rural Female"])` before and after doing the preceding.

This solution works, but I would have thought that there would be a way to control the grid lines from inside the `dotplot` function, perhaps using a panel function.  Is there a way to do that?  (An authoritative "No" could count as a correct answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `col.line = "transparent"` inside `panel.dotplot` should solve this issue. See also `?panel.dotplot`.

```
dotplot(VADeaths[, "Rural Female"], panel = function(...) {
  panel.dotplot(..., col.line = "transparent")
})
```

[image: solution]

Comment: Excellent--thanks.  Just what I was looking for.  Getting the information one wants from the help pages is sometimes a black art.