# Change colors of x-axis labels in dotplot from Lattice package R

Tags: r, plot, lattice, dot

I was wondering if there was a way to change the color of certain x-axis labels on a dotplot that I created using the lattice package in R.

This is an example of my data/code:

```
State <- factor(c("AZ", "AR", "NJ"))
Value <- c(1.2, 4.5, 2.0, 1.5, 4.0, 1.4)
Year <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2005, 2005, 2005)

p <- dotplot(Value ~ State, groups = Year, main = "Test Data",
        xlab = "State/Territory", ylab = "Data", auto.key = TRUE)
```

I would like AZ and AR to be grouped together (be the same color text in the x-axis, we can make it blue)

I would like NJ to be its own group (be a different color in the x-axis text, we can make it pink)

Could I also draw a vertical line in the graph to better separate the groups?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlling this on legacy plotting systems is extremely complicated as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489624/). One approach might be to use a modern plotting system like `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(State = factor(c("AZ", "AR", "NJ")),Value = c(1.2, 4.5, 2.0, 1.5, 4.0, 1.4), Year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2005, 2005, 2005))

ggplot(data,aes(x=State,y=Value,color = State, shape = as.factor(Year))) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) + scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","blue","pink")) + scale_shape_discrete(name = "Year") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = c("blue","blue","pink")), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2.5) + labs(title = "Test Data", x = "State/Territory", y = "Data")
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 2):

Well, just for fun, sometimes lattice is not that complicated and it is still remarkably fast doing some massive plots.

In your case, you need to specify the group to be `State` and then use col to specify 3 colors, and do panel.abline inside the panel function, for example:

```
dotplot(Value ~ State, groups=State,
main = "Test Data",
col=c("blue","blue","brown"),
panel = function(x, y,...) {
         panel.dotplot(x, y,levels.fos = unique(x),...)
         panel.abline(v=2.5)
       })
```

[image]

Of course one downside is you cannot easily specify another group variable, for example year here.

Comment: I also gave the passing function with `...` a try. I couldn't figure out how to color the the x-axis labels though.  Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

```
# This could be a solution with lattice

dotplot(Value ~ State, data, groups = State,
        scales = list(x = list(col = ifelse(levels(data$State) %in% c("AZ", "AR"), "blue", "deeppink2"))),
        par.settings = list(superpose.symbol = list(col = c("blue", "blue", "deeppink2"), pch = 16)),
        panel = function(...) {
          panel.abline(v = 2.5)
          panel.dotplot(...)
        })
```

Comment: Could you please flesh out what is expected to go where you have `...` in the function?